# Move series up in grafana dashboard

Tags: graphite, grafana

I would like to move series up and down in Grafana / Graphite dashboard.
I'm aware to the special button "move up" and "move down", but I need for example to move 4 rows from the bottom to the top in a board of 30 series.

So if each row will be 2 mouse clicks for moving 1 line up = 240 mouse clicks ; =[

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you have a click-fest waiting for you - it seems you are not the only one [wishing for the drag 'n drop reordering](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2253).

> "Would just like to add my vote, this would be quite handy. It would
>   save up to half an hour of time of tediously clicking "Move up" for a
>   bunch of new data rows on a bunch of new panels."